# Probability of win after tie with a maximum number of points

Tags: probability

Two players play a game. At some point there is tie. After a tie a player wins when he has more than two points than the other player.
As a result, the number of rallies played until either player wins is even.

Let $L \hspace{1mm}  \epsilon \hspace{1mm} N_0$

The probability that player A wins a point is $p$.
In order to have 2*L* points after the tie, it suffices

1. the players win alternatively during the first 2(*L*-1) points:

$$ 2p(1-p)^{L-1} $$

2. player A scores 2 successive points thereafter.

$$ p^2 $$

Together

$$ p^2(2p(1-p))^{L-1} $$

Which can rewritten as

$$  \frac{p^2}{1-2p(1-p)} $$

However in badminton, there is a special rule in the case of a tie.
If the score is 20-20, a player must win two successive rallies to win the game. If the game reaches 29-29, the first player to get their 30th point wins.

What is the probability that A wins after a score of (20,20) is reached in a badminton game?

Comment: The special rules make it very likely that there is no simple expression.  You just have to go through the whole tree and compute it.

Comment: This is not clear.  Presumably it depends on *which* tie you are talking about. If the tie is $29-29$ then, according to you, the answer is $p$.  If the tie is $28-28$ then the answer is $p^2(3-2p)$  And, as you can see from the latter form, it gets more complicated as you consider other ties.  In general you can get a simple recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I adjusted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are tied at $20-20$

With $A,B$ having  winning probabilities of $p, 1-p=q$ for a point,

P(they are tied at $21-21) = pq+qp = 2pq$
P(they are tied at $22-22) = 2pq(pq+qp)= 4p^2q^2$,
.....
P(they are tied at $29-29) = 512p^9q^9$

thus P(A wins the match from $20-20) = 512p^{10}q^{9}$